# TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate with Navigation Properties EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, treeview

I have three linked Entities (Categories->Types->Classes) with one to many relationship.
Is it possible to bind only Categories entity and represent the rest using Navigation properties and`HierarchicalDataTemplate` ? 

I imagine something like this :

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">

            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" >
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Types}" />

                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeName}" />

                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClassName}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

        </TreeView>
```

Comment: Is that pseudocode?  You're not setting the datatype and other things.  WPF or winforms?  Either way though, conceptually, yes it will work, but your implementation is a bit off :)

Comment: Thanks, my implementation is just a draft cause i'm still asking for the possibility

Comment: Then yep, you can definitely do this!

Comment: any useful ex or article in this way ? or could you answer with a general schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this recently, in a WPF project, I've updated the Types to match your names and Nav Properties.

You might want to consider changing Type/Class to something more specific since they're used as keywords in the c# language, but I think you get the idea

```
  <!-- The Root Category Table -->
           <HierarchicalDataTemplateDataType="{x:Type Entities1:Categories}" ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" >
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding ., Converter={Converters:DataTypeImageConverter}}" />
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
              </StackPanel>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
           <!-- Your Type Table -->
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Entities1:Type}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}" >
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding ., Converter={Converters:DataTypeImageConverter}}" />
                 <TextBlock  Text="{Binding TypeName}" />
              </StackPanel>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
           <!-- Your Class Table-->
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Entities1:Class}">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding ., Converter={Converters:DataTypeImageConverter}}" />
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClassName}" />
              </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
```

What this will do is, it will match the datatype in the tree - If it matches `Category`, it will create the stackpanel, then start another branch, using the navigation collection `Types`.

For `types`, it will do the same basic thing - create the panel for that item, then another branch, for it's navigation collection `Class`.

If it's `class`, it will only create the panel, since it's a `DataTemplate`, not a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`

Comment: --this is an awesome answer. But how did you add these `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s to the tree's ItemsSource without it showing the error "ItemTemplate is set more than once"? Thanks!